# unix ls directory with sub-directory exists

Tags: unix, ls

In Unix, is it possible to use one command ONLY to list the directory if a sub-directory exists?

For example, I would like to list the directory name if it contains a sub-directory called "division_A"

```
/data/data_file/form_100/division_A
/data/data_file/form_101/division_A
/data/data_file/form_102/division_A
```

The desired result would be

```
form_100 
form_101 
form_102
```

I can only use 2 command lines to realize the goal.

```
cd /data/data_files
echo `ls -d */division_A 2> /dev/null | sed 's,/division_A,,g'`
```

So I would like to ask if anyone can use one command to proceed it.

Many Thanks!

Comment: The beauty of unix is that it provides you with a set of building blocks.  You can write a tool that does whatever you want, and then invoke it as a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find /data/data_file -type d -name division_A -exec sh -c 'basename `dirname {}`' \; 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Aw, my bad. I misread the task to mean "contains any directory" in which case you'd probably get duplicate base paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the weird `..`, you can just do:

```
$ ls -d /data/data_file/*/division_A/..
```

It will output something like `/data/data_file/form_100/division_A/..` and you can access it like normal folders.